# Http request broken after upgrading to .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, http, ssl, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm posting telemetry data to the Application Insights data collector endpoint at `https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track` using `HttpClient`.

This works fine when using .NET Core 2.0. However, after upgrading to .NET Core 2.1 all requests fail with HTTP status `500 Internal Server Error` and an HTML response body that looks like this:

[image: IIS 8.5 Detailed Error]

(*It's an IIS 8.5 Detailed Error page*)

In .NET Core 2.1 they have [changed](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.1/2.1.0.md#networking-performance) how `HttpClientHandler` works and added an `AppContext` switch that allows us to keep the old behavior:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```

Indeed, setting this switch fixes the problem!

But I'd like to avoid using that switch:

- Firstly, because I'd like to use the new stuff. It *must* be better :-)
- Secondly, because that switch changes behavior for **all** new `HttpClientHandler` instances. Not just the one I'm using to post data to the Application Insights endpoint.

I've tried to figure out what's causing this by looking at the traffic using Wireshark. Trying to interpret HTTPS traffic on that low level is beyond me. I did find something suspicious in the TLS handshake though.

Both the `SocketsHttpHandler` (that doesn't work) and the legacy `WinHttpHandler` (that do work) use TLS 1.2. However, only the `WinHttpHandler` uses the [TLS Certificate Status Request extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCSP_stapling). Could that be the reason why requests are failing?

In any case, the TLS connection is setup a request is sent and a response is retrieved. And apparently there is an error on the *server side* while processing the request.

I'd like to figure out what's causing this problem. Any help is appreciated!

---

As suggested by @mjwills I changed my code so that it uses HTTP (not SSL) and post to a local program that allows me to capture the request. (I didn't figure out how to do this in a clean way in Wireshark, so I ended up writing my own little capture tool based on `TcpListener`):

**Capture when using the new `SocketsHttpHandler`:**

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/x-json-stream
Content-Encoding: gzip
Host: localhost:12345

A
[...10 bytes of data...]
F4
[...244 bytes of data...]
0
```

**Capture when using the legacy `WinHttpHandler`:**

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/x-json-stream
Content-Encoding: gzip
Host: localhost:12345

a
[...10 bytes of data...]
f4
[...244 bytes of data...]
0
```

These are the differences:

- `WinHttpHandler` wants to keep the connection alive while `SocketsHttpHandler` does not.
- `WinHttpHandler` use lower case hex for chunk lengths while `SocketsHttpHandler` use upper case.

The first 10 bytes contains the gzip header. The remaining 244 bytes contains the gzip encoded json telemetry data.

Comment: What if, before you send that request to the real endpoint you send it to localhost without https. Use wireshark to see what is passed. Then swap the value of `UseSocketsHttpHandler` and repeat. What is different between the two?

Comment: i'm sure you upgraded your project correctly but i'm just adding this link (it's for preview-1 however still useful) for a ref for the upgrade steps: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/upgrading-aspnet-core-2-application-aspnet-core-2-1-preview-1

Comment: @mjwills I did check that using Fiddler but I didn't see any difference at all. Which caused me to think it had something to do with TLS. Is that enough or should I check for differences using Wireshark too?

Comment: @JohnB Thanks, but I'm not using ASP.NET

Comment: @mjwills See updated question

Comment: Do you still get the same 500 status code when you disable SSL using the new SocketsHttpHandler?

Comment: If I use plain http when posting to Application Insights, it'll just respond with a 307 redirection to the https endpoint.

Comment: I'm having trouble with a vendor API as well when UseSocketsHttpHandler is true 